# Code-first in Entity Framework columns doesn't exists migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a migration class as you can see :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MigrationsConfiguration>("DefaultConnection"));
    }

    public DbSet<Line> Lines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NdtReport> NdtReports { get; set; }
}
```

And migration class:

```
public class MigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public MigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

In one of my classes, I removed some columns and added another column, but when I run the application I get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in  EntityFramework.dll Additional information: ALTER TABLE
>   DROP COLUMN failed because column  'FinNumber' does not exist in table
>   'FitUps'.

Why ?

Comment: are you using mixture of automatic migrations and explicit migrations ?

Comment: @Sampath i don't know all migration code that i have i put in the post

Comment: OK,can you do it again after restarting the visual studio instance ?